# Postgresql JDBC Table Valued Parameters

Tags: postgresql, java

**MSSQL** has a great feature called **Table Valued Parameters**. It allows you to pass a table of a custom data to stored procedures and functions.

I was wondering what is the equivalent , if exists, in **PostgreSQL**, using **JDBC**? I know about the option of passing Arrays as a function parameters, but that seems limited to Postgresql data types.

Consider the following PL/pgSQL code:

```
CREATE  TYPE number_with_time AS(
_num   float,
_date  timestamp
);
```

and this function header:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(arr number_with_time[])
```

Can anyone post a **JAVA** code using JDBC driver of calling that function with an array of the user defined data type?

Thanks

Comment: Should be over at http://dba.stackexchange.com